# Avoid useEffect to be triggered when one nested dependency changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My form has 3 fields, `lambda`, `period` and `filterPattern`. When the values of `lambda` and `period` change, it will trigger `handleSearch`. However, I don't want `handleSearch` to be triggered when `filterPattern` changes.

If I don't put `filterPattern` in the dependency array, then `handleSearch` cannot get the latest value of `filterPattern`.

How to avoid useEffect to be triggered when one nested dependency changes? Thanks.

```
const getLogQuery = useCallback(() => ({
  lambda,
  period,
  filterPattern,
}), [lambda, period, filterPattern]);

const handleSearch = useCallback(async () => {
  await getLambdaLogs(getLogQuery());
}, [getLogQuery]);

useEffect(() => {
  handleSearch();
}, [handleSearch]);

const getLambdaLogs = async (query) => {
  const logs = await LambdaService.getLambdaLogs(query);
  setLogItems(logs);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a few assumptions, but the second argument of `useEffect` are its dependencies, the things it watches to know when to fire.  So instead of

```
useEffect(() => {
  handleSearch();
}, [handleSearch]);
```

Which doesn't make any sense, to watch a function and then call that function if it changes, change that to

````
useEffect(() => {
  handleSearch();
}, [lamba, period]);
```
````

Comment: I also tried that and eslint complains I have missing dependency 'handleSearch', so I put it in the dependency array.

Comment: You can disable (i.e. ignore) that rule for that line if you like.